# What imaginations of Lebesgue spaces or other Banach spaces do people intuitively share?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, banach-spaces

At several occasions I heared people discussing about the „colors“ of Lebesgue spaces $L^p$: $L^2$ is red, $L^1$ is white, $L^\infty$ is black, and the other $L^p$ are blue or violett. Of course this is somehow inspired by the rainbow spectrum - still I always found it fascinating that many mathematicians share this imagination or feeling about these spaces and their relations, even though this seems not written in a text book or somewhere else, at least to my knowledge.

I would like to know if there are more people sharing this or a similar imagination? Are there other imaginations of Banach spaces that people intuitively share?

Please feel free to close this question if it is too soft or not appropriate.

Comment: I always imagined Hilbert spaces to be brown, but that is probably just my synesthesia

Comment: For me, the Lebesgue spaces have different shapes, not different colors.

Comment: It is still shape, rather than color, but I suggest you to look at page 313 of Matousek's "Lectures on Discrete Geometry", and the paper of Vitali Milman cited there.